# Create a view with top N per group rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create a view that stores the top 200 rows for each userId from another table that has userId as one of its columns.
Found a way to do this using user-defined variables in `SELECT`, but then MySQL does not allow views with variables in the `SELECT`.

This is a part of the `SELECT` statement to be used in the view:

```
select *,@num:= if(@userId = userId, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
@userId := userId as dummy from (SELECT @userId:=0, @num:=0) as init
```

Is it possible to replace `@userId` and `@num` with functions instead? Similar examples would of great help!!

Comment: Yes, you can - but it will be slower :-(

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * FROM results;
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+
| id | discipline | member | event | value |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |      2 |     4 |    10 |
|  2 |          1 |      1 |     4 |     8 |
|  3 |          1 |      2 |     5 |     9 |
|  4 |          2 |      3 |     5 |     9 |
|  5 |          1 |      2 |     6 |    11 |
|  6 |          1 |      2 |     7 |    11 |
|  7 |          1 |      2 |     1 |    11 |
|  8 |          1 |      2 |     3 |     7 |
|  9 |          1 |      1 |     8 |     8 |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Say I want to get the top 3 'value' results for each member. In the event of a tie, I'll take the lower 'event' first...

```
SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank
  FROM results x 
  JOIN results y 
    ON y.member = x.member 
   AND (y.value > x.value OR (y.value = x.value AND y.event <= x.event)) 
 GROUP 
    BY x.member
     , x.value
     , x.event 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=3;
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+---------+
| id | discipline | member | event | value | rank    |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+---------+
|  2 |          1 |      1 |     4 |     8 |       1 |
|  9 |          1 |      1 |     8 |     8 |       2 |
|  7 |          1 |      2 |     1 |    11 |       1 |
|  5 |          1 |      2 |     6 |    11 |       2 |
|  6 |          1 |      2 |     7 |    11 |       3 |
|  4 |          2 |      3 |     5 |     9 |       1 |
+----+------------+--------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: This solution works but as you already mentioned, its very slow especially since there are thousands of records in my table. The approach with user-defined variables works quite fast. Is there a way to still use the variables approach inside the view using functions in place of variables.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Either, construct a view using the method above or use your faster solution and forego the view.